# Присвоить класс строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть такое меню.

```
<ul>
 <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#">Текст</a></li>
 <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#">  - Текст</a></li>
 <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#">  - Текст</a></li>
 <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#">Текст</a></li> 
 <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#">Текст</a></li>     
</ul>
```

Как можно с помощью jquery в ссылке которая содержит " - " удалить " - " и присвоить ей класс для дальнейшего оформления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.list-group-item').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text.substr(0,4).indexOf('-') > -1) {
         $(this).addClass('second-level');
         $(this).text(text.substr(4));
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Код работает в отдельном файле. А когда я его пишу на живом сайте, то ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в количестве пробелов перед и после минуса

Comment: я изменил, попробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо, так работает!!!